How to Dynamically Update Document Title and Favicon in a React Application Using Data from an API
I am building a React application and I need to dynamically update the document title and favicon based on data fetched from an API. Specifically, I want to use the brandName field from my API response to set the document title and favicon.
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" **href={profileImage}**/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>**{brandName}**</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.jsx"></script>
  </body>
</html>


Make use of 'useState' and 'useEffect'
you need to make a function that will fetch and set the value of the icon and brand name from the API. After the data has been fetched, you can use javascript to update the said title and favicon dynamically.
function App() {
  const [brandName, setBrandName] = useState('');
  const [profileImage, setProfileImage] = useState('');

//Data Fetching
  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      try {
        const response = await fetch('YOUR_API_ENDPOINT');
        const data = await response.json();
        
        //Set the value of the brandName and favicon/profile
        setBrandName(data.brandName);
        setProfileImage(data.profileImage);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
      }
    }

    fetchData();
  }, []);

//Update the brandName dynamically
  useEffect(() => {
    if (brandName) {
      document.title = brandName;
    }
  }, [brandName]);

//Update the profileImage / favicon dynamically
  useEffect(() => {
    if (profileImage) {
      const link = document.querySelector("link[rel*='icon']") || document.createElement('link');
      link.type = 'image/svg+xml';
      link.rel = 'icon';
      link.href = profileImage;
      document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link);
    }
  }, [profileImage]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Welcome to {brandName}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;


How about directly changing the document object after acquiring the data from the API?
const data = await fetchMyData();

document.title = data.brandName;

const faviconElement = document.querySelector("link[rel='icon']");
if (faviconElement) {
  faviconElement.href = data.profileImage;
}


First you need to fetch some data
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
function App() {
  const [brandName, setBrandName] = useState('');
  const [profileImage, setProfileImage] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch('REQUESTED_URL');
        const data = await response.json();
        setBrandName(data.brandName);
        setProfileImage(data.profileImage);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching brand data:', error);
      }
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Set document title
    if (brandName) {
      document.title = brandName;
    }

    // Set favicon
    if (profileImage) {
      const favicon = document.getElementById('favicon');
      favicon.href = profileImage;
    }
  }, [brandName, profileImage]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Welcome to {brandName}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

Then update your index.html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link id="favicon" rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="default-icon.svg" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Default Title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.jsx"></script>
  </body>
</html>

